# Wear2.0 HCE service not run

Tags: android, hce, android-wear-2.0

I tried to use this example for huawei watch2.0, but HCE service did not run. Do watch really support HCE?
example:https://github.com/googlesamples/android-CardEmulation

Comment: First off welcome to StackOverflow. We are glad you're here. You'll get a much better answer if you can provide a code sample of what you've already tried and a better description of what went wrong. "service didn't run" is not very helpful

Comment: gloable rom support HCE，huawei watch not support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Huawei Watch 2 does support HCE. Communication performance isn't too good though. If the readers signal isn't good enough or antennas don't match, the user experience might be poor or no communication might get established at all. In the latter case one might get the illusion that the HCE service isn't running. When testing with our own product, communication success was very much dependent on exact positioning of the watch relative to the product.